# GKE / kube-ui password not showing via `kubectl config view`

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kubectl

Trying to simply connect to the master ui ui interface.

I guess we got it all in the title, Just tried any commands related to auth, nothing to do. `kubectl config view` won't provide a user and its associated password.

Hope that'll sound obvious to some;

Best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running the Google gke, you may not find your admin pass(web-ui too) with `kubectl config view`.

However, you can get it from https://console.cloud.google.com/ --> Container Engine --> Show Credentials.